# Wrong System.Web.Mvc update

Tags: asp.net, nuget

I had System.Web.Mvc v4.0.0.0 added in the GAC, so I installed manually Mvc via nuget with "Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 5.2.3".

I have installed System.Web.Mvc v5.2.3.0 now,
[image: NuGet manager]

and System.Web.Mvc v4.0.0.0 in the GAC
[image: GAC]

I have this in Web.config:

```
 <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

I build and run the project and I get the next error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

But I have configured and added MVC v5.2.3.0 package . Why this error appears?

**SOLVED**
Dereference System.Web.Mvc
References -> Right click -> Mange NuGet Packages... -> Uninstall MVC -> And now "Install".

Comment: This save my day : )
WTF of remove and reinstall to solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assembly you see listed is from the [GAC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). That doesn't necessarily mean you're using it in the project. If you want to see the actual package installed in your project, right click the project and click "Manage NuGet Packages".

Uncheck version 4 on the Add Reference screen, then use the Package Manager Console to install the specific version via NuGet. Make sure you have the correct project selected to install the package into.

Comment: Oh, ok! I've seen now. But why has the GAC an old dependence? When I'm developing I reference DLLs in the GAC. And I installed with "Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 5.2.3" again for the project runs.

Comment: @Joe You should not reference GAC DLL's for things you can obtain outside the main framework, such as MVC. MVC is now delivered out of band via NuGet instead of via the GAC. In fact, with the new ASP.NET 5 on .NET Core there won't be a GAC at all.

Comment: Then the GAC has references put by Microsoft (because yes) and I must only add references in the GAC that don't be in others frameworks. Right? I read the MSDN documentation and I don't pretend create another question, but I don't understand this...

Comment: @Joe The GAC is for assemblies that are part of the .NET Framework. MVC used to be delivered as part of the .NET Framework. However, that has changed because MVC is now delivered out of band via NuGet. Therefore, if you want to use newer versions of MVC you must obtain the assemblies via NuGet rather than referencing the GAC.

Comment: Ok, but for test I've purged System.Web.Mvc in the GAC references now and I've installed with NuGet the newest MVC and I've put the reference to the newest MVC in ~/Web.config. "Build"->"Mvc doesn't exist in the current context".

Comment: Second test: Add System.web.Mvc v4.0.0.0 in the GAC and install Mvc v5.2.3.0 from NuGet. "Build"->"Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0"

Comment: @Joe You'll need to edit your question to include the relevant configuration and show the code that's failing.

Comment: @Joe Like I said before, uncheck the reference in the Add References screen.